# How to Include links in html or jquery alert boxes?

Tags: php, jquery, html, hyperlink

When the website onload I just want a alert box which gives links.
I think we cannot add links in JavaScript alert box.
Is there any way we can include links in alert box any other box when the site is load?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot put links in AlertBox (javascript), there are implementations as appear in answers. its a dialog based on div which have show/hide events.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Jquery UI dialog box` to show all links in popup on page load.

You can show required html in jquery ui dialogbox

Please reffer: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

And there are also some other plugins available for displaying data in popup.

Answer (score 1):

use **window.confirm** instead of **alert**

```
if (window.confirm('If you click "ok" you would be redirected . Cancel will load this website ')) 
{
  window.location.href='https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/index.html';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an alert box that includes link.

This is done by using a custom modal that acts as a alert box.

http://jquerymodal.com/ has examples on how can you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (window.confirm('redirecting the website to google')) 
    {
      window.location.href='https://www.google.com/';
    };
```